# Getting No response from google direction api

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am using google direction api to get direction/routes between two places.

When I query

> http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=New%20York%20LaGuardia%20Airport%20Marriott,%20Queens,%20NY,%20United%20States&destination=200%20e%2057th%20st%20ny&sensor=false

Iam getting Status = NOT_FOUND.

But when I search this path from **New York LaGuardia Airport Marriott, Queens, NY, United States** to **200 e 57th st ny** using https://maps.google.com/. Google display a direction path between these two places. You can see this via link: [link](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=New%20York%20LaGuardia%20Airport%20Marriott,%20Queens,%20NY,%20United%20States&daddr=200%20e%2057th%20st%20ny%20ny&hl=en&ll=40.773392,-73.884945&spn=0.069419,0.131664&sll=40.76858,-73.86776&sspn=0.001085,0.002057&geocode=FSIVbgIdTd-Y-yFK-Kbg2ID1zylL28wekF_CiTFK-Kbg2ID1zw;FdPybQIdUVqX-ynfbUYx5FjCiTFQ1lgZbCZrpw&mra=ls&t=m&z=13&iwloc=ddw0)

What should I do to get the reponse from google api.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps uses many sources of locations data including Places results.  Look to me like the directions service can't find "New York LaGuardia Airport Marriott, Queens, NY, United States" (because it isn't an address).  If I use the Places API, that can find it.

[example using the javascript APIs](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_example_geo2.asp?addr1=New%20York%20LaGuardia%20Airport%20Marriott,%20Queens,%20NY,%20United%20States&addr2=200%20e%2057th%20st%20ny&place=1&geocode=2)