# Distance calculate from autocomplete inputs: certain locations in API dropdown selection don't get assigned usuable location data

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a simple distance calculator on a page I'm making, and the distance is calculated between 2 points from an input field using data from google maps (Places Autocomplete).

I load the info from google using this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places">
```

I've also tried adding the adsense and geometery libraries seperated by comma, but from the documentation it doesn't seem like I really need those for this problem. Without them the places I want to see *do* appear, it's just that sometimes they aren't used.

The dropdown does function and I can see the results I want to use. Most of the time it will, but for certain vague places it does not. For example, the distance from X to "Tufts University, Medford, MA, United States" (autocompleted by google) will calculate just fine. However, from X to "Foxwoods Resort Casino, Ledyard, CT, United States" (also autocompleted by google) will not. These are both large campus-style layouts, and I understand that it's not an exact address, but in most cases the broadest name for a large multi-address destination will work fine. So why not on Foxwoods, for example? It appears in the autocomplete drop down menu provided by google, so why doesn't it have some kind of address value?

The options I'm using for the map are pretty standard, I have it restricted to the US but that's about it. Except:

```
travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
```

That's how it uses the points to get the mileage, unsure if it's related but that's the only other thing I can find that might change behavior.

If there's any more info I need to provide let me know, I'm wondering how to lick this and I just can't. I'm hoping that it's possible without going into a whole geolocation thing :P

Thanks!

edit: here's the distance calculation function using the "start" and "end" autocompleted inputs:

```
        var fromText = document.getElementById('start');
    var fromAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(fromText);
        var toText = document.getElementById('end');
        var toAuto = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(toText);



    function calcRoute() {
        var start = document.getElementById("start").value;
        var end = document.getElementById("end").value;
        var distanceInput = document.getElementById("distance");


        var request = {
            origin:start, 
            destination:end,
            travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
        };

        directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                distanceinkm = response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000;
                distanceinmiles = (distanceinkm * 0.621371);
                distanceinmiles = distanceinmiles.toFixed(2);
                distanceInput.value = distanceinmiles;
            }
        });
```

Comment: show your code for calculating the distance , there are different parameters that you can choose for the accuracy and other stuff that may be defaulting to something that is not working

Comment: Hi Scott, I edited the function into my question (calcroute). Thanks.

Comment: "Foxwoods Resort Casino, Ledyard, CT, United States" is a place, it can't be found by the geocoder or the directions service. The autocomplete service returns the coordinates associated with the result.  Use those to compute the route.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Places API not marking routes for some places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20587003/google-places-api-not-marking-routes-for-some-places/20587897#20587897)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting No response from google direction api](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15634925/getting-no-response-from-google-direction-api/15638831#15638831)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google Directions API and Using maps.google.com give different Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13374236/google-directions-api-and-using-maps-google-com-give-different-response/13374391#13374391)

Comment: I see... I noticed in one of your duplicate questions that it was recommended to change the formatted address before running the calculation. Would that work in this case? If it gets the coordinates could it then turn those coordinates into a usable address?

Comment: Note: for some reason you have tagged this as [google-maps-api-2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-2), that version of the Google Maps Javascript API is deprecated and turned off.  You are using the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) (based on your include of the script).

Comment: Oops sorry, updated!

Comment: you see the answer right?  don't use the text value in the textboxes , use the coordinates returned from the autocomplete service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Foxwoods Resort Casino, Ledyard, CT, United States" is a [place](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places), it can't be found by the [geocoder](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding) or the [directions service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions). The [autocomplete service](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_place_information) returns the coordinates associated with the result. Use those to compute the route.

[Example of getting coordinates](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places-autocomplete#get_searchbox_information) from the documentation (as pointed out by [Scott Selby](https://stackoverflow.com/users/813523/scott-selby) in the comments)

Comment: in the link in this post "autocomplete service" go to the section "Get Search Box Information"  , this is how you get the coordinates instead of the text value of the place